# Unable to install Inkscape on ubuntu 14.04

Tags: dependencies

Hi I am new to Linux Ubuntu 14.04. I wanted to install Inkscape but it has shown following error(Dependencies as it says):

```
inkscape: Depends: python:any (>= 2.7.1-0ubuntu2) but it is a virtual package
          Depends: libaspell15 (>= 0.60.7~20110707) but 0.60.7~20110707-1ubuntu1 is to be installed
          Depends: libatkmm-1.6-1 (>= 2.22.1) but 2.22.7-2ubuntu1 is to be installed
          Depends: libc6 (>= 2.7) but 2.19-0ubuntu6.1 is to be installed
          Depends: libcairo2 (>= 1.10.0) but 1.13.0~20140204-0ubuntu1 is to be installed
          Depends: libcairomm-1.0-1 (>= 1.6.4) but 1.10.0-1ubuntu3 is to be installed
          Depends: libfontconfig1 (>= 2.9.0) but 2.11.0-0ubuntu4.1 is to be installed
          Depends: libfreetype6 (>= 2.2.1) but 2.5.2-1ubuntu2.2 is to be installed
          Depends: libgc1c2 (>= 1:7.2d) but 1:7.2d-5ubuntu2 is to be installed
          Depends: libgcc1 (>= 1:4.1.1) but 1:4.9-20140406-0ubuntu1 is to be installed
          Depends: libgdk-pixbuf2.0-0 (>= 2.22.0) but 2.30.7-0ubuntu1 is to be installed
          Depends: libglib2.0-0 (>= 2.35.9) but 2.40.0-2 is to be installed
          Depends: libglibmm-2.4-1c2a (>= 2.36.2) but 2.39.93-0ubuntu1 is to be installed
          Depends: libgnomevfs2-0 (>= 1:2.17.90) but it is not going to be installed
          Depends: libgomp1 (>= 4.2.1) but 4.8.2-19ubuntu1 is to be installed
          Depends: libgsl0ldbl (>= 1.9) but it is not going to be installed
          Depends: libgtk2.0-0 (>= 2.24.0) but 2.24.23-0ubuntu1.1 is to be installed
          Depends: libgtkmm-2.4-1c2a (>= 1:2.24.0) but 1:2.24.4-1ubuntu1 is to be installed
          Depends: libgtkspell0 (>= 2.0.10) but it is not going to be installed
          Depends: liblcms2-2 (>= 2.2+git20110628) but 2.5-0ubuntu4 is to be installed
          Depends: libmagick++5 (>= 8:6.7.7.10) but it is not going to be installed
          Depends: libpango-1.0-0 (>= 1.14.0) but 1.36.3-1ubuntu1 is to be installed
          Depends: libpangocairo-1.0-0 (>= 1.14.0) but 1.36.3-1ubuntu1 is to be installed
          Depends: libpangoft2-1.0-0 (>= 1.14.0) but 1.36.3-1ubuntu1 is to be installed
          Depends: libpangomm-1.4-1 (>= 2.27.1) but 2.34.0-1ubuntu1 is to be installed
          Depends: libpng12-0 (>= 1.2.13-4) but 1.2.50-1ubuntu2 is to be installed
          Depends: libpopt0 (>= 1.14) but 1.16-8ubuntu1 is to be installed
          Depends: libsigc++-2.0-0c2a (>= 2.0.2) but 2.2.10-0.2ubuntu2 is to be installed
          Depends: libstdc++6 (>= 4.6) but 4.8.2-19ubuntu1 is to be installed
          Depends: libxml2 (>= 2.7.4) but 2.9.1+dfsg1-3ubuntu4.3 is to be installed
          Depends: libxslt1.1 (>= 1.1.25) but 1.1.28-2build1 is to be installed
          Depends: zlib1g (>= 1:1.1.4) but 1:1.2.8.dfsg-1ubuntu1 is to be installed
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Did you add external PPAs or "mess" with the packages in other ways perhaps? Or are you using the stock repositories?

Comment: By that list it just says those dependencies are going to be installed. Did you follow through with clicking okay and let it run through its paces?

Comment: @AndreaLazzarotto via External PPAs.

Comment: If you perform these modifications, you should mention them. May I ask why you didn't install Inkscape from the official repositories? By the way, please update your question adding information about the PPA you used.

Comment: What are official Repositories?
I searched for "how to install Inkscape on ubuntu 14.4" it showed me the PPAs results etc.
P.S: Again i am not pro at LINUX.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To install Inkscape, just press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> on your keyboard to open Terminal. When it opens, run the command(s) below:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:inkscape.dev/stable
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install inkscape
```

[image]

Comment: inkscape : Depends: libgnomevfs2-0 (>= 1:2.17.90) but it is not installable
            Depends: libgsl0ldbl (>= 1.9) but it is not installable
            Depends: libgtkspell0 (>= 2.0.10) but it is not installable
            Depends: libmagick++5 (>= 8:6.7.7.10) but it is not installable
    
           
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.

Comment: Use synaptic to fix broken packages.  If it not installed, do `sudo apt-get install synaptic`. and from the edit menu choose fix broken packages.  see [here](https://copy.com/DhttTnZjYEwS).

Comment: anum@SK:~$ sudo apt-get install synaptic
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package synaptic is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'synaptic' has no installation candidate
KILL ME :|

Comment: Try `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade`  Also make sure that you have these [repositories](https://copy.com/HGJl6NjKQoA1) checked prior to running the previous command.

Comment: I reverted what I added (PPAs) earlier & rechecked the repositories. I got it! Thank You :)

Comment: If you encounter a dependency problem, try `sudo apt-get upgrade inkscape` after having properly added and updated the repository.